# AWS Codebuild: docker run options

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I have a build project in AWS CodeBuild.
This project uses a docker image stored in AWS ECR.
I have to modify the options which are used to run the container - specifically, I want to add `--init`.
I see there is a `initProcessEnabled` option which can be used for ECS, but I don't understand how to combine this with CodeBuild.